# Recursive Floodfill Overflowing

Tags: java, flood-fill

```
public void floodFill(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9) {
        if (mines[x][y] == 0) {
            btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            floodFill(x - 1, y);
            // floodFill(x + 1, y);
            floodFill(x, y - 1);
            // floodFill(x, y + 1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the floodFill code I'm using for a minesweeper-like game I'm making. However, as you can see 2 parts are commented out. As soon as I un-comment it and run the program.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.NullComponentPeer.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:95)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:99)
at Minesweeper.BoardBuild.floodFill(BoardBuild.java:98)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The answer that Fls'Zen came up with in chat, just in case anyone else ever has this problem

```
public void floodFill(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9) {
        if (mines[x][y] == 0 && btn[x][y].getBackground() != Color.GRAY) {
            btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            floodFill(x - 1, y);
            floodFill(x + 1, y);
            floodFill(x, y - 1);
            floodFill(x, y + 1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Increase Stack size 
2. Make sure you do not get a infinite recursion (I would log which fields are already filled for testing)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When those lines are uncommented, you call floodFill for both `x - 1` and `x + 1`. Consider what happens when you call floodFill for `x - 1`. It also calls floodFill for `x + 1` which is the `x` value that called floodFill. You have floodFill calling itself for the same two `x` values, the original `x` value, and the original `x - 1`.

If you're going to use recursion, you should pick one 'direction' (+ or -) and stick with it. Otherwise, you'll need to add something to track which coordinates have been evaluated.

**Edit:**
The following code will avoid recursion when a cell has already been processed by the algorithm. It accomplishes this by checking the background color of the current coordinates. If the background is already gray, then it assumes it has already processed the coordinates and won't process them again.

```
if (mines[x][y] == 0 && btn[x][y].getBackground() != Color.GRAY) {
    btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    floodFill(x - 1, y);
    floodFill(x + 1, y);
    floodFill(x, y - 1);
    floodFill(x, y + 1);
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: @FlsZen and how would i keep track of it? I thought of a 2D boolean array set to false as default which mirros the buttons and when it changes the BG, it sets the value to true. where would i check this though?

Comment: Ah — you don't check the background color. Maybe you should add `&& btn[x][y].getBackground() != Color.GRAY` to your `if` statement.

Comment: @FlsZen to the if (mines[x][y] == 0)? i just tried that "if (mines[x][y] == 0 && btn[x][y].getBackground() == Color.GRAY)" and all it does is gray the one i clicked. Nothing else

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `!= Color.GRAY`, I edited my comment. I'm a little confused. Are you trying to track cells with mines[x][y] or btn[x][y]?

Comment: @FlsZen the != Color.GRAY does the same thing, What do you mean by track cells? like the values of each button? im using mines[][] which has the value of 99 for bombs, and 0 for no bomb. 1-5 are for proximity to the bomb

Comment: I mean track the cells that the method has already processed. The issue is that it doesn't know that it already performed its fill action on a cell, so it repeats the process on a pair of cells until the stack overflows. Is your goal here to fill the grey backgrounds from a given point outward?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21853/discussion-between-flszen-and-exikle)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't recording which squares you've already checked, so it's infinitely looping over the entire board.